# adb can't find my device (sony xperia J)

Tags: android, adb

1. I use windows 7 64 bit
2. My phone is a Sony Xperia J
3. my phone is in debugging mode
4. drivers for my phone are installed
5. 'adb devices' returns: "List of devices attached" with nothing else
6. I have removed all related software and installed it again

There are quite a lot of other things I tried already, but since I've been trying to solve this for 2 days already, I basically already tried every possible solution that is out there on the internet. Please help.

Comment: What does the device manager tell you, is there an unrecognized device?

Comment: One of my menagerie of Android test devices refuses to attach to ADB via USB.  I eventually worked around the problem by installing the ADB over Wifi widget.  So long as your device and your PC are on the same local network, starting this widget gives you an IP address and port (displayed on the widget itself) that you can connect to via ADB's connect command (e.g., 
connect 192.168.1.105:8000
) It is a lot slower than USB but quite usable.

Answer (score 6):

I found out that you must put your phone in Mass Storage mode, as default is MTP mode. As simple as that @#! And I spent hours trying all sorts of things reading posts.

Settings / Xperia / USB Connectivity / USB Connection Mode and select MASS Storage, not MTP. I did uncheck Install PC Companion. It work right away. No need to Update drivers, no need to change the android_winusb.inf. You may need to kill adb.exe before trying again adb devices.

That was it for me :)

Comment: That was the solution for us too.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for Sony Xperia Tablet S:

- enter Sony repository in SDK manager (tools -> manage add-on sites -> user-defined
  sites - new)
  http://dl-developer.sonymobile.com/sdk_manager/Tablet-SDK-Add-on.xml
- in main SDK manager, select "repository" (bottom part of screen)
- browse for Sony entry, install "Sony Tablet SDK Add-On"

*Modifying the Google USB driver*

- install google usb driver in Android SDK Manager
- gives subdirectory $ANDROID_SDK\sdk\extras\google\sub_driver
- this directory contains android_winusb.inf

  - add

  **(this will have to be different in your case)**

  ;SONY Sony Tablet S
  %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_054C&PID_05B4&MI_01

  to sections

  [Google.NTx86]
  [Google.NTamd64]
- open cmd shell
- cd c:\
- mkdir .android
- cd .android
- echo 0x54c >> adb_usb.ini       **(maybe different number)**

*Installing the Modified driver*

- kill any adb process first
- connect tablet, be sure debug usb mode is selected on the device
- open device manager -> other devices, exclamation mark device

  - update driver
  - browse for driver software
  - !! pick from list
  - !! have disk
  - !! select android_winusb.inf
  - ignore all warnings about unsigned driver
  - select Android ADB Interface
- the device should now show up as "Android Device - Android ADB Interface"
  (still in device manager
- the above should do the trick.
- try 
  $ANDROID_PATH\sdk\platform-tools\adb  devices

  it should list the new device now (before it will be inivisble)

*Info used:*

links in next post due to restriction

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that is no Android driver for Sony Xperia J installed

Solution here : install Sony Companion http://www-support-downloads.sonymobile.com/Software%20Downloads/PC%20Companion/Sony%20PC%20Companion_Web.exe

Enjoy!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21412702)

Comment: @GastónSaillén This is not a link-only answer. The answer is "install Sony Companion", which although terse is in this context perfectly acceptable. It then provides a link to download the Sony Companion installer.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, the link is stale

Comment: @AlexP. Then edit that link out or replace it with an updated link. It does not change the fact this is **not** a link-only answer.